# What exactly was the Parabellum's role?

Tags: bodacious-space-pirates

In Morestsu Pirates / Bodacious Space Pirates, The Parabellum is hired by Gruier to make sure that Marika finishes her business with the Space Pirates before her final exams begin.

[image]

The ship makes a grand entrance at one stage, but during the show I couldn't see any way that the ship/crew actively helped Marika and the Bentenmaru.

I might have missed something, but, what does the Parabellum and its crew do to help Marika?

Comment: Do you remember which episode this was from?

Comment: We find out that they were hired to help in the final episode, and I think the first appearance was episode 22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Towards the end of episode 22, the anti-pirate ship, Grand Cross has just defeated the Big Catch and it was implied that it would have went after Marika and the Bentenmaru next.

Marika had to make a decision on whether to attempt to rescue the crew of the Big Catch, or escape.

It was that moment when the Parabellum FTL jumps in the battlefield and engages the Grand Cross ultimately forcing it retreat.

This allows Marika the Bentenmaru to rescue the crew of the Big Catch. (which eventually got destroyed because the fires couldn't be controlled and it ignited the ammo cache)

---

So you can argue that without the help of Parabellum, the crew of the Big Catch would likely have perished. It is also possible Marika and the Bentenmaru would have perished as well if they decided to stick around to rescue the crew of the Big Catch.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense now, I guess at the time of their arrival the bentenmaru crew also didn't know what was happening ^^;